# Проблема с pythoh Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, error404

При использовании virtualenv выдает ошибку

```
E:\rrr>virtualenv -v
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'
```

Так при любой команде с ним.

Пробовал переустановить питон, сейчас

```
E:\rrr>python -V
Python 3.7.2
```

Стоял pip 18.1 нашел способ поправить ошибку таким способом

```
> python -m pip uninstall pip
> python -m ensurepip
> python -m pip install -U "pip<10"
```

Не помогло, подскажите как пофиксить

Answer (score 4):

```
python -m venv env
```

`virtualenv` - команда для питона 2, с версии 3.6 нужно способом как выше.

Ну и эта проблема, как я посмотрел у многих не только с virtualenv, там и работа pip у многих проблемная, но аргумент `-m` запускает библиотечный модуль как скрипт и это вроде решает проблему.

Answer (score -1):

Поменял системный язык виндоус на английский, и всё заработало.